# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea

after downloading and installing IntelliJ IDEA I finnaly was able to start a project. I decided to go with the Hello World template, but when I try to compile it just never does. I can let it 1 hour and it would still be loading.

Thank you!

In this image you can see that it says it compiles. but actually doesn't..., it's just loading but never finishes compiling:
[IntelliJ IDEA never stops compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6wVo.png)

Comment: IntelliJ is a continuous build tool out of the box, meaning that by default it will automatically compile the source file you have open.  Your screen capture doesn't look like anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: I understand, but for me it nevers stop compiling, I can't run this simple Hello World program.

Comment: Obviously you can't see it from the image, but I was trying to show you that  the compile never ends.